# CSS3 selector for next matching sibling

Tags: html, css

I am trying to come up with a CSS3 selector for the below HTML:

```
<input data-type="fillpart" type="checkbox" name="cough, " checked="true">
<ignore></ignore>
<fillpart explicitlyset="true" name="cough, ">cough, </fillpart>
...
<input data-type="fillpart" type="checkbox" name=“fever, " checked="true">
<ignore></ignore>
<fillpart explicitlyset="true" name=“fever, ">fever, </fillpart>
...
<input data-type="fillpart" type="checkbox" name=“flu, " checked="true">
<ignore></ignore>
<fillpart explicitlyset="true" name=“flu, ">flue, </fillpart>
```

All of the elements are siblings, and there might be additional elements where `...` are. The elements in question are always in a sequence of three (3). Currently, I have CSS as below:

```
fillpart {
  background: #a5d2a5;
}
```

It colors the text inside `<fillpart>`, while the tag itself is obviously ignored, since it is not something that browsers support. I want to alternate the background value depending on whether previous tag matches `input[checked='true']` or `false`.

Is this possible with CSS3?

Thank you

Comment: add a class instead to these elements and add styling to this class

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To style elements after a checked input-field, you can use the CSS next-selector (+):

```
fillpart {
    background-color: #a5d2a5;
}

input:checked + ignore + fillpart {
    background-color: red;
}
```

this will make the `fillpart` after the `ignore`, after the `checked input-field` have a red background-color

**EDIT:**

Actually, you can use the `~`-selector, which selects every `fillpart` element that are preceded by a checked input-field:

```
fillpart {
    background-color: #a5d2a5;
}

input:checked ~ fillpart {
    background-color: red;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use plus sign (+) in your selector:

`input[checked="false"] + ignore + fillpart`

view my example below:

```css
fillpart {background: #a5d2a5;}
input[checked="false"] +ignore+ fillpart{background: red;}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>
  <input data-type="fillpart" type="checkbox" name="cough, " checked="true">
  <ignore></ignore>
  <fillpart explicitlyset="true" name="cough, ">cough, </fillpart>
  ...
  <input data-type="fillpart" type="checkbox" name=“fever, " checked="false">
  <ignore></ignore>
  <fillpart explicitlyset="true" name=“fever, ">fever, </fillpart>
  ...
  <input data-type="fillpart" type="checkbox" name=“flu, " checked="true">
  <ignore></ignore>
  <fillpart explicitlyset="true" name=“flu, ">flue, </fillpart>

</body>
</html>
```